# How to move decimal up a position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, number-formatting, react-native-textinput

So basically the scenario is we have initial value `0.00`

if the user enter any value like 2 than the decimal value should be 0.02

if the user enter any value like 3 than the decimal value should be 0.23 (appending to previous value of 0.02)

if the user enter any value like 5 than the decimal value should be 2.35 (appending to previous value of 0.23)

so if the user has entered 12345 it should be 123.45 .

I want something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are asking to divide a number by ten, but I may not understand the question. Code is below:

```js
function d() {n=prompt("enter your number"); alert(n/100);}
```

```css
button {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "d();">move decimal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your input as a string, push the number to the end of it, then convert back to number.

```
 let strValue = currentValue.toFixed(2).replace(".", ""); // Remove the decimal
 strValue = (parseInt(strValue, 10) * 10 + digit).toString(); // Shift left and add the new digit
 return parseInt(strValue, 10) / 100; // Convert back to a number with two decimal places
};
```

An example:

```
let currentValue = 0.00;
currentValue = addDigitToRight(currentValue, 2); // 0.02
currentValue = addDigitToRight(currentValue, 3); // 0.23
currentValue = addDigitToRight(currentValue, 4); // 2.34
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here it is managed to work with if** `last digits are 00`;

```js
function decimalUtil(num){
  return (num/100).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(decimalUtil(1200)); //12.00
console.log(decimalUtil(1222)); //12.22
console.log(decimalUtil(12)); //0.12
console.log(decimalUtil(12225588)); //122255.88
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ReactJS implementation in TypeScript:

```
import { ChangeEvent, FC, useState } from "react"

const DecimalizedInput: FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  /**
   * Decimalizes the value
   * @param {string} targetValue
   * @returns {number}
   */
  const decimalize = (targetValue: string) => {
    const currentValue = parseFloat(targetValue)

    /**
     * For handling value deletion
     */
    if (currentValue < value) return currentValue / 10
    /**
     * For handling value addition
     */
    return currentValue * 10
  }

  const onValueChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const targetValue = e.target.value
    /**
     * Ignoring non-numeric characters
     */
    if (targetValue && !targetValue.match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/)) return
    /**
     * Decimalizing the value
     */ else if (targetValue) setValue(decimalize(targetValue))
    /**
     * Resetting the value
     */ else setValue(0)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={
          // For displaying the value with 2 decimal places
          value.toFixed(2)
        }
        onChange={onValueChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default DecimalizedInput
```

You can get the code [here](https://gist.github.com/nawaazkortiwala/59a43a6e111231354cdf59df2fcc2281) as well.

Comment: @AdnanAshraf this works with value deletion as well.